# External Library in WebStorm as CSS with an http link

Tags: javascript, css, webstorm, libraries

Does someone know how to load an External Library in WebStorm as CSS with an http link? It gives me the option to "Download Library" in the warning.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css"/>
```

[image: Link Tag]

However, when I download it, the External Library loads as a .js
and because it downloads it as .js, the warning still appears to me and the project doesn't index the library properly.

[image: Added library]

I've tried repairing the IDE, or watching if I could rename it in some way, but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.